# I am building a React app which can convert any video to text. For that I am using AWS Transcribe and DynamoDB

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

So I am building an application on React which converts user videos into text using AWS transcribe and saves it to the database. I thought of using an AWS dynamo table as a database but I am completely new to AWS and can not figure out what is needed and how to do structure.

## Things I was able to attain

- I was able to convert any video put in was S3 bucket into text using Lambda and Aws transcibe.
- I m able to create the UI for the app.

## Things I need help with

- How to save data such that can have all the transcription created by the user into one user table

  ```
      user-id
         |
          ----- Transcribed / [ Array of all the transcribed data]
         |
         ------- User details
  ```

something like the above structure but I am not sure how to achieve it.

Any help will be appreciated Thank you.

Comment: For a React solution. are you building a Front end using React and a Backend that invokes AWS Services.. For example, you can build a Spring BOOT backend that uses the AWS Java V2 SDK to invoke Amazon DynamoDB and Transcribe.

Comment: @smac2020 I am building the frontend just for now but I m curious do I need to make a backend or can I handle it from the frontend?

Comment: I'm trying to build a similar app using this API: https://docs.rev.ai/get-started/.
But i'm stuck because im using Nextjs and i think it needs Socket.io which im having trouble to implement in Nextjs. I don't know if there's another way to get the data other than Socket.io.